# asp.NET and SQL Server datetime issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datetime

I am having hard time to store date information into the datetime column of SQL Server.

I get the input from the user for three columns:

1. Creation Date
2. Preparation Date
3. Next Preparation Date

I use calendarextender and format the date as "yyyy/MM/dd". When all the fields have date, they are stored in the DB as for instance, 16-10-2016 (dd-MM-yyyy).

At this point I have two issues:

1. These columns are optional, when some of them are empty my code does not work (I assume because datetime cannot be null). To overcome this, I am using the following code snippet but still does not work.

   ```
   DateTime? creationDate= null;

   if (creationDateTextbox.Text != null && creationDateTextbox.Text != "")
   {
       creationDate= Convert.ToDateTime(creationDateTextbox.Text);
   }
   ```
2. When I fetch the dates from DB, they are shown as 10/16/2016 (MM-dd-yyyy) which is different how I formatted it. I would like to show it in the format user enters them.

Comment: `if(creationDateTextbox.Text != null && creationDateTextbox.Text != "")` can be simplified to `if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(creationDateTextbox.Text)`

Comment: when in doubt store it as ticks or whatever is the lowest fullsize time in integers in the db

Comment: I solved the first issue. I formatted it as MM-dd-yyyy by using the calendarextender while storing data and now it gives the same format when I fetch it from DB. However, the second issue continues. I cannot run my code when one of the dates are not selected by the user.

Answer (score 4):

Dates do not have a format while stored in a database. It is actually usually just a very large `long` that counts the number of milliseconds from a set starting date.

If you want to store the format you need to stop storing it as dates and instead just treat the text as text in the database, however if you do this you won't get the advantage of sorting or filtering by a date range because it will just be seen as text.

Answer (score 0):

Date time doesn't have any format You can format is as a string, suppose your DateTime type database field `dt` which contain date as `10/16/2016 (MM-dd-yyyy)` then you can convert it

```
string s = dt.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to one of your questions is here: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.dataformatstring(v=vs.110).aspx)
You can use data annotations to format the dates that you get from your SQL DB. I'm assuming that you're using EF6; if not, you can change the field to a varchar in SSMS, and store the date as a String.

And the second, I'm unclear about, but if what you want is for your SQL DB column to be optional, you can use the Optional data annotation for that.

Comment: If there is no date selected by the user for one of the date fields, my whole code does not work (because datetime cannot be empty in SQL Server I assume).

Comment: As far as I know, you can make any field nullable in SQL Server. You can also do so in EF6. I'd wager your .NET app is faltering, not the SQL transaction. Do you have an error message, and have you used breakpoints to find the line of code where the app fails?

Comment: I tested it and the null date fields are the problem.. Somehow SQL Server does not accept null datetime columns.